# Efficiently canceling key frame animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a key frame animation to show a card-dealing effect in Swift. I use a second animation (using .BeginFromCurrentState ...) to cancel the dealing if you press a button. This has worked effectively on simple single view animations. However here there is a 2-10s delay after pressing the button, presumably while each cancel animation is run. Is there a simpler smoother way of achieving what I want (immediately canceling the dealing).

Here's the code snippet that sets up the dealing animation:

```
    let durationSlice = 1.0/Double(numCards*numPlayers+1)
    var durationSliceStart : Double = 0
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(FiveKings.ANIMATION_250MS*(Double(numCards)*Double(numPlayers)+1), delay: 0.0 ,
        options: [.CalculationModeCubic],
        animations: {
            for iCard in 0..<numCards {
                durationSliceStart = Double(iCard*numPlayers) * durationSlice
                //translate the cards off the pile and to each mini Hand (and they stay visible)
                for iPlayer in 0..<numPlayers {
                    //Animate the card into view at the start of this set
                    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(durationSliceStart+Double(iPlayer)*durationSlice, relativeDuration: 0.0, animations: {
                            pileCardViews[iCard*numPlayers + iPlayer].alpha = 1.0
                        })


                    //add a random amount of translation and rotation to simulate messy cards
                    let messyX = CGFloat((drand48()-0.5) * MESSY_CARD_XY_OFFSET) * self.mDrawPile.bounds.width
                    let messyY = CGFloat((drand48()-0.5) * MESSY_CARD_XY_OFFSET) * self.mDrawPile.bounds.height
                    let messyRotation = CGFloat((drand48()-0.5) * MESSY_CARD_ANGLE) * 2.0 * 3.14

                    //convert the destination miniHand into the coordinates of mDrawPile
                    let miniHandLayout = self.mGame.players.getPlayer(iPlayer).miniHandLayout!
                    miniHandDestinationPoint = miniHandLayout.cardView.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), toView: self.mDrawPile)
                    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(durationSliceStart+Double(iPlayer)*durationSlice, relativeDuration: durationSlice, animations: {
                        pileCardViews[iCard*numPlayers + iPlayer].transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(
                            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14+messyRotation),
                            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(miniHandDestinationPoint.x + messyX, miniHandDestinationPoint.y + messyY))
                        if iCard == 0 {miniHandLayout.cardView.alpha = 1.0}
                    })

                }

            }//end iCard
            //animate a card to the DiscardPile
            let discardPileDestination = self.mDiscardPile.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), toView: self.mDrawPile)
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(durationSliceStart+Double(numPlayers)*durationSlice, relativeDuration: durationSlice, animations:
                {
                    pileCardViews[numCards*numPlayers].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(discardPileDestination.x, discardPileDestination.y)
                    pileCardViews[numCards*numPlayers].alpha = 1.0
            })
        },
        //completion block removes the added cards
        completion: {(_ : Bool) in
            //remove the added cards
            for pcv in pileCardViews {pcv.removeFromSuperview()}
            self.afterDealing()
        }
    )//end UIView.animateKeyFramesWithDuration
```

Here's the code that is run when you press the "Skip dealing" button:

```
    if !mDealingPileCards.isEmpty {
        for pcv in self.mDealingPileCards {pcv.stopAnimation()} //also seems to call completion handler
        self.mDealingPileCards.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.setShowHint(stringKey: "toDisableDealing", setShowHint: FiveKings.HandleHint.SET_AND_SHOW_HINT, hintLevel: GameDifficulty.MEDIUM)
    }
```

and the implementation of `stopAnimation` is an extension to UIView:

```
func stopAnimation() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState],
        animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT: I have tried using `...layer.removeAllAnimations` but the same delay problem occurs, perhaps while the completion handler is run?

Answer (score 2):

To cancel animations, just say `removeAllAnimations` to every layer (or the layer of every view) that was being animated. You will also need to decide where you now want that view to appear, but that's a different question (in other words, you have to think of what cancellation actually consists of).

Comment: Yes, I tried that already. The same problem occurs - there is a long pause while the removeAllAnimations completes.

Comment: "there is a long pause while the removeAllAnimations completes" Really? Are you sure you don't have a threading problem?

Comment: In my code snippet posted above, if I replace pcv.stopAnimation() with pcv.layer.removeAllAnimations() I get the same "stalling" in the UI. Can you point me to what I could do to track down "a threading problem"? There's nothing else happening.

Comment: Thank you @matt for your skepticism, because it pointed me in the right direction. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to the question (which itself poses another question) is that either the `stopAnimation` (calling another animation using `.BeginFromCurrentState`) or `..layer.removeAllAnimations` will in fact cancel the animations. However in my case there was additional UI work going on in the completion block, which apparently does not run until the scheduled time. In other words, even if you cancel/remove the key frame animations individually, the completion block is delayed.